# Who and where X-Forwarded-For header in user's request is added?

Tags: http, http-proxy

X-Forwarded-For is a HTTP header which is used to identify the IP Address of originating user. I was wondering "where" this header is added in the request and "who" actually adds it? Is it your browser itself? your ISP? Maybe HTTP server? or the destination server? From Source to Destination where it is being added like maybe just after your browser generates a request or maybe after your ISP or just before the destination server or "is it added in the incoming request"?

Answer (score 4):

This header is normally only inserted by a forward proxy when there is an upstream proxy that it needs to identify the originator to, otherwise if a forward proxy inserted this header for requests over the internet, it would normally be deemed to be leakage of potentially sensitive information.

So it's rarely used for forward proxies, and mostly used by reverse proxies to identify the internet-based client to the back end web server, since web servers behind reverse proxies usually see all connections as coming from the internal interface of the reverse proxy.

Alternatives to this are 
 - the Proxy Protocol, which sends this data over the connection prior to the actual request in a different format
 - reverse NAT, which keeps the external client IP on the back-haul connection

Other times you see X-Forwarded-For in practise is where some clients insert the header to try to gain elevated privileges, if the reverse proxy passes the value through for example.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a forward proxy (a proxy used by your web server), this header may be added by the proxy to tell the IP(s) of the originating user, so that web servers down the path will know that the IP making the request - which will be the proxy's - is not the IP that actually made the request.

In case of a reverse-proxy (put in front of web servers in order to do caching, TLS, serving static content, etc), this header contains the IP of the originating user as seen by the reverse-proxy (the servers behind it will see all requests coming from the reverse-proxy's IP, so this header is essential for them to know what is the real IP who made the request).

Of course, if no proxies are involved this header doesn't exist.